# A Children's Rhyme Riddle

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Riddle me this, riddle me that,
>
> No riddles, but rhymes will you find in my hat!
>
> A cake and a cup, a rake and a ball,
>
> A bowl with a goldfish, don't let it fall!
>
> Now that they've fallen, let's pick up some things,
>
> But first we should start with some kites and some strings!
>
> Solving riddles is fun, even one so, so small
>
> When you're sat in the house, doing nothing at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are

> the Cat in the Hat (from Dr Seuss)

and

> everything in the riddle describes things that happen in that book.